# Understanding IF statement in an SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am inserting a text string into my mySQL database.

The text string example:  `[1,0,1]`

Positions in a string represent  valueOne, valueTwo , valueThree.

I want my query to detect Zero and Ones in a text string and output another string that is associated with the Zero and Ones values, such as:

```
Select quiz_answer from quizes
WHERE
IF valueOne  > 0 THEN
     result = pie;
 IF valueTwo > 0 THEN
     result = cookies;
  IF valueThree >0 THEN
     result = fruit;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if` is utterly unnecessary (and as written, syntactically incorrect).  Just use boolean logic:

```
select quiz_answer
from quizes
where (valueOne  > 0 and result = pie) or
      (valueTwo > 0  and result = cookies) or
      (valueThree > 0 and result = fruit);
```

Note that if `pie`, `cookies`, and `fruit` are intended to be strings, they should be surrounded by single quotes.

Comment: I'm getting no results. To clarify, the text string in my db field looks like this: [1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0] (including the brackets).

Comment: This doesn't work with or with out the bit I've added at the end: AND question_id=79

Comment: select
   answer_data 
from
   wp_learndash_pro_quiz_statistic 
where
   (
      valueOne > 0 
      and result = 'pie'
   )
   or 
   (
      valueTwo > 0 
      and result = 'cookies'
   )
   or 
   (
      valueThree > 0 
      and result = 'fruit'
   )
   or 
   (
      valueFour > 0 
      and result = 'pie'
   )
   or 
   (
      valueFive > 0 
      and result = 'cookies'
   )
   
WHERE
   question_id = 79

Comment: I actually have "AND question_id=79, not WHERE question_id=79

Comment: @phillystyle123 . . . I have no idea what your question refer to.  This answers the question t hat was actually asked.

Comment: Just reread - I think the stack edits to my question made it less clear -apologies. Allow me to clarify: a string in my db text field: [1,0,1] - the string includes the brackets. I need to assign a value to each one of these numbers depending upon where they are in the string.

Comment: Using this string as an example (which includes the brackets): 

[1,0,1]

When the first number in the string = 1 value = pie, when the second number in this string =1 value= cookies, when the third number in this string =1 value = fruit. So the output for this string would be cookies, fruit.